# How to store modified field name to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a page where I have text boxes to add contact details like Name, Address, phone number, and email address. I want to save into database table which field is modified along with the name of the modifies user and time. suppose if I change phone number so the phone number filed should be saved into db. How to get the modified field name and save into db.

Model:

```
public partial class Log
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string ModeifiedField { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
}
```

Controller :

```
        private readonly LogEntities _db = new LogEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Log model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            _db.UserActivityLogs.Add(model);
            _db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Added;
            _db.SaveChanges();

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

View :

```html
@model Sample.Models.Log

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <form>

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Date, new { @Value = @DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()})
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserName, new { @Value = @User.Identity.Name })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ModifiedField, new { @Value = @ViewBag.ModifiedField, })
        <br />
        <br />

        <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)</p>
        <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address)</p>
        <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)</p>
       <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Emailaddress)</p>
        <button type="submit" title="Submit">Upload Image</button>

        @ViewBag.Message
    </form>
}
```

Comment: You will need to read it from the database, and compare to the new object. Alternatively, use a database trigger.

Comment: You could create a status property in the current object. Then you'd have to create another db table that tracks the modifications.

Comment: How bold of you to assume only one field changed.  =)  Generally, you'd pick up the original from the db, compare it to the modified one, and go from there. Some frameworks can do this for you (search for change tracking and whatever your ORM is, such as entity framework core or whatnot), depends on what you're using. But do pull a fresh copy on the server (not this hidden field here), for several reasons, such as hacks to client side code or concurrent users modifying the data.

Comment: Entity Framework has `ChangeTracker` and half work is already done for you. You just need to plugin into it and add log entities. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/change-tracking-in-entity-framework.aspx. Long ago, I wrote my own data persistence framework that would add entries to the main transaction. But it was `DataTable` based. Probably was faster than EF but more work to write it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Triggers.

Please refer [documentation for columns updated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

You will have to create trigger on the tables for which you want to keep track of updated columns.

Then trigger will give you list of updated columns which you can keep in some metadata table (or return to code - depending on your requirement).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To check and update the records in database for only the changed fields can be achieved using this way:

```
    private readonly LogEntities _db = new LogEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Log model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var existingLog = _db.UserActivityLogs.Where(x => x.ID == model.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (existingLog == null)   //Create Case
            {
                _db.UserActivityLogs.Add(model);
                _db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Added;
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else                      //Update Case
            {
                _db.UserActivityLogs.Attach(model);

                //Check for each property and set the IsModified flag to true only for updated records
                if (model.UserName != existingLog.UserName)
                {
                    _db.Entry(model).Propert(x=> x.UserName).IsModified = true;
                }
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```